# Upload file on amazon S3 with PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, upload, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a picture on my amazon S3 via their PHP SDK. So I made a little script to do so. However, my script doesn't work and my exception doesn't send me back any error message.

I'm new with AWS thank you for your help.

Here is the code :

Config.php

```
<?php 

return array(
'includes' => array('_aws'),
'services' => array(
  'default_settings' => array(
      'params' => array(
          'key'    => 'PUBLICKEY',
          'secret' => 'PRIVATEKEY',
          'region' => 'eu-west-1'
      )
    )
  )
);

?>
```

Index.php

```
 <?php


//Installing AWS SDK via phar
require 'aws.phar';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$bucket = 'infact';
$keyname = 'myImage';

// $filepath should be absolute path to a file on disk                      
$filepath = 'image.jpg';

// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = S3Client::factory('config.php');

// Upload a file.
try {

$result = $s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'       => $bucket,
    'Key'          => $keyname,
    'SourceFile'   => $filePath,
    'ContentType'  => 'text/plain',
    'ACL'          => 'public-read',
    'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY'
));

 // Print the URL to the object.
    echo $result['ObjectURL'] . "\n";
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}

?>
```

EDIT : I'm now using this code but its still not working. I don't even have error or exception message.

```
    <?php

require 'aws.phar';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$bucket = 'infactr';
$keyname = 'sample';
// $filepath should be absolute path to a file on disk                      
$filepath = 'image.jpg';

// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => 'key',
    'secret' => 'privatekey',
    'region' => 'eu-west-1'

    ));

try {
    // Upload data.
    $result = $s3->putObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $keyname,
        'SourceFile'   => $filePath,
        'ACL'    => 'public-read',
        'ContentType' => 'image/jpeg'
    ));

    // Print the URL to the object.
    echo $result['ObjectURL'] . "\n";
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: Are you running this from the Web or the command line ?

Comment: Try it from the command line to see the errors.

Comment: I've never use any console with s3. Are you using [s3tools.org](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) to connect?

Comment: Yes `s3cmd`.  You don't need `s3cmd` to try your script. You can just run: `php <yourscript>.php`

Comment: @Rico Excuse me for my stupid question but how do I connect to my S3 then? Where do I run my command line? (mac osx)

Comment: @Rico http://aws.amazon.com/cli/?

Comment: from the Linux command line

Comment: @Rico OK so I assume you are using linux as OS. Can you tell me why I need to use the command line to run my script ? Why can't I just run my php script on my browser?

Comment: You can run on your browser too, it's just that from the command line you can see the errors. I suppose you can look at your web server logs for errors too.

Comment: Holy shart guys — it's time to start using Composer like a grown-up.

Comment: hey @casusbelli i am facing same problem. got any solution for same ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this (from the [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpPHP.html)):

```
<?php

require 'aws.phar';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$bucket = '<your bucket name>';
$keyname = 'sample';
// $filepath should be absolute path to a file on disk                      
$filepath = '/path/to/image.jpg';

// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => 'your AWS access key',
    'secret' => 'your AWS secret access key'
));

try {
    // Upload data.
    $result = $s3->putObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $keyname,
        'SourceFile'   => $filepath,
        'ACL'    => 'public-read'
    ));



    // Print the URL to the object.
    echo $result['ObjectURL'] . "\n";
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}

?>
```

It works fine for me as long as you have the right credentials. Keep in mind that the key name is the name of your file in S3 so if you want to have your key have the same name of your file you have to do something like: `$keyname = 'image.jpg';`  . Also, a jpg is generally not a `plain/text` file type, you can ommit that `Content-type` field or you can just simply specify: `image/jpeg`

Answer (score 2):

```
$s3 = S3Client::factory('config.php');
```

should be

```
$s3 = S3Client::factory(include 'config.php');
```

Answer (score 2):

For those looking an up to date working version, this is what I am using

```
// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => $s3Key,
        'secret' => $s3Secret,
        ],
    'region' => 'us-west-2',
    'version' => "2006-03-01"
));

try {
    // Upload data.
    $result = $s3->putObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $s3Bucket,
        'Key'    => $fileId,
        'SourceFile'   => $filepath."/".$fileName
    ));
    return $result['ObjectURL'];
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to explain is by showing the curl, and how to build it in php - the pragmatic approach.
Please don't stone me for ugly code, just thought that this example is easy to follow for uploading to Azure from PHP, or other language.

```
$azure1 ='https://viperprodstorage1.blob.core.windows.net/bucketnameAtAzure/';
$azure3 ='?sr=c&si=bucketnameAtAzure-policy&sig=GJ_verySecretHashFromAzure_aw%3D';
$shellCmd='ls -la '.$outFileName;
$lsOutput=shell_exec($shellCmd);
#print_r($lsOutput);
$exploded=explode(' ', $lsOutput);
#print_r($exploded);
$fileLength=$exploded[7];
$curlAzure1="curl -v -X PUT -T '" . $outFileName . "' -H 'Content-Length: " . $fileLength . "' ";
$buildedCurlForUploading=$curlAzure1."'".$azure1.$outFileName.$azure3."'";
var_dump($buildedCurlForUploading);
shell_exec($buildedCurlForUploading);
```

This is the actual curl

```
shell_exec("curl -v -X PUT -T 'fileName' -H 'Content-Length: fileSize' 'https://viperprodstorage1.blob.core.windows.net/bucketnameAtAzure/fileName?sr=c&si=bucketNameAtAzure-policy&sig=GJ_verySecretHashFromAzure_aw%3D'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are the code for upload image/file in amazon s3 bucket.

```
function upload_agreement_data($target_path, $source_path, $file_name, $content_type)
{
    $fileup_flag = false;

    /*------------- call global settings helper function starts ----------------*/
    $bucketName = "pilateslogic";
    //$global_setting_option = '__cloud_front_bucket__';
    //$bucketName = get_global_settings($global_setting_option);
    /*------------- call global settings helper function ends ----------------*/

    if(!$bucketName)
    {
        die("ERROR: Template bucket name not found!");
    }

    // Amazon profile_template template js upload URL
    $target_profile_template_js_url = "/".$bucketName."/".$target_path;

    // Chatching profile_template template js upload URL
    //$source_profile_template_js_url = dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))).$source_path."/".$file_name;

    // file name
    $template_js_file = $file_name;

    $this->s3->setEndpoint("s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com");
    if($this->s3->putObjectFile($source_path, $target_profile_template_js_url, $template_js_file, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ, array(), array("Content-Type" => $content_type)))
    {
        $fileup_flag = true;
    }
    return $fileup_flag;
}
```

Comment: $source_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/".$advertiseImage;
    $file_name = rand();
    $content_type = "image/jpeg";
    $target_path = "FreeImage";
    $this->upload_agreement_data($target_path,$source_path,$file_name,$content_type);

Comment: function getBucketURL($imageType, $uri)
 {
  $bucket = "pilateslogic";
  $newUri = $imageType."/".$uri;
  $fileURL = $this->s3->getAuthenticatedURL($bucket, $newUri, 1000, $hostBucket = false, $https = false);
  return $fileURL;
 }